# Stabilizing variance that decreases over time in oscillating timeseries

Tags: time-series, biostatistics, signal-processing

I have some oscillating timeseries data that decreases in mean and variance over time.  I am interested in stabilizing or normalizing the variance with some relatively straightforward transformation.  The timeseries represents expression of a gene. All values are positive with CVs ~0.4 for first third of timeseries (~40 data points). In latter two-thirds of timeseries (~80 data points) the mean level drops to 80% of first third and CVs of oscillations are ~0.2

Does anyone have any suggestions on what to try?  Most of the examples I've seen involve transformations on timeseries whose variance is increasing as a function of the independent variable.

Comment: Can you give some context? What does your timeseries represent?

Comment: Timeseries represents expression of a gene.  All values are positive with CVs ~0.4 for first third of timeseries (~40 data points).  In latter two-thirds of timeseries (~80 data points) the mean level drops to 80% of first third and CVs of oscillations are ~0.2.

Comment: Can you please add this new information into the post?

Comment: @user13999, if you know that variance decrease is the function of time, you can estimate the function parameters and transform your data with this function. You can also log-transform your data. Are you interested in more details?